# Node JS trying to download a number of images. Stream seems to keep being closed

Tags: node.js

I'm looping through quite a lot of images to download from a website using this function:

```
const fileGet = (url, path, callback) => {
request.head(url, (err, res, body) => {
        request(url)
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
    })
    .on('error', function(err, res) {
        console.log(err + res)
    })
}
```

It seems to get so far and then the stream seems to be closed. I've been doing some googling and people mention it could be trying to resolve too many dns lookups in a given time.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
node:events:371
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.domain.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
Emitted 'error' event on Request instance at:
    at Request.onerror (node:internal/streams/legacy:62:12)
    at Request.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Scraper\node_modules\request\request.js:877:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:193:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:158:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'www.domain.com'
}
```

I've tried hard coding the IP/Host name in my Hosts file, and tried putting a pause in the requests, same problem. I've also upgraded to the last version of Node (16.4.0)

Still the same.
There is a lot of debate about this issue online. Has it even been resolved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is interested, it was a DNS lookup issue, and sorted it by using DNS Cache.

Just wrapper my whole download process with an initial look up, and the rest ran like a dream.